# How to generate a TextView from a buttonclick event in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to create textviews according to a number selected from a spinner. Example: If I select 2, then 2 textviews should created in the another layout.

Comment: Please somebody help me! I'm really new to android studio and I really need to build this inoder to continue my project. It'll be a great help if someone can post me a code for this

Comment: Is there any possibility to generate such a thing using android studio?

Comment: it's not an android studio problem. You have to create a layout with a spinner and a textview. then in your java Activity depending of the value you have selected you have to cycle the textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
TextView[] tv4 = new TextView[value1];

TextView[] tv5 = new TextView[value2];

for(int i=0;i<value1;i++){
    tv4[i]=new TextView(Home.this);
    tv4[i] = new TextView(Home.this);
    tv4[i] .setText("Test 1"+i);
    tv4[i] .setTextSize(20);
    tv4[i] .setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params4.leftMargin = 200+(i+10);
    params4.topMargin = 280;
    tv4[i] .setLayoutParams(params4);
    rR.addView(tv4[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                txt.setText("Hello world");
            }
        }
```

Try in this way. Remember to create the TextView in your layout xml

Comment: of course mine was an example. instead 50 he has to put the value from spinner he has selected

Comment: I tried but it is not creating any textvew in my layout

Comment: TextView txt = new TextView(YourActivity.this); // here i should have to use my new activity right?

Comment: in there you have to put your current activity....the textviews you have to create must be created in another activity or the same in where there is the spinner?

Comment: actually i did create a new project to test this. So i have added the spinner and textview in the activity_main and created another activity to get that generated textview. but at the MainActvity when i give the newly created activity name it gives an error

Comment: which error? btw, try to create everything in same activity for now. Spinner and textviews.

Comment: Oki i'll try that way then

Comment: Now it doesn't give any error. but it is not creating any text view

Comment: See my edit.. Maybe try to debug and try to understand if enter in the for loop..

Comment: Yeah i can create now but how can i create it in another layout

Comment: Do You mean another activity? By the way, can you accept my answer?